# How do I define a function that can be used with different variables and produce an output in python?

Tags: python

I have tried to use this function to create an output inside the variable finish but nothing seems to work

```
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~ '''

def puncrem(x,y):
    for char in str(x):
       if char not in punctuations:
           y = y + char
    return y 


start = "h%e*l(l&o"

finish = ""

puncrem(start,finish)

print(finish)
```

Comment: Thats not how functions work. `finish = puncrem(start,finish)`. Probably dont need 2nd argument for function.

Comment: You can't do that because you can't change a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use return values like this:

```
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~ '''

def puncrem(x):
    y = ""
    for char in str(x):
        if char not in punctuations:
            y = y + char
    return y

start = "h%e*l(l&o"
finish = puncrem(start)
print(finish)
```

Comment: Can we use "globals()['finish'] = y" to set the value of finish from the "puncrem" function itself without returning y?

Comment: Technically, you can... but please don't.